# List and access directory in go

Tags: go

i need some help in golan to write a program that can search through a given directory and its subdirectories to  look for a particular word word in each of them.

this what i have so far to list the directories and save them as an array. now i want to check  each of them to see if it has children, if yes, i should open it until i reach the last level of the tree.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"


)

func main() {

    d, err := os.Open("/Perkins")
   // fmt.Println(d.Readdirnames(-1))

    y, err:=d.Readdirnames(-1) // 
    fmt.Println(y)
    for i:=0; i<len(y); i++{
        if y[i]!=" "{
            Folders:=y[i]
            temp,err:=os.Open("/"Folders) //how do i out the array element as a path?
            fmt.Println (temp)

            fmt.Println(err)
            }
    }
```

Comment: What's your exact question / issue?

Comment: the first open enable me to have all the files of the folders Perkins. but when i try to loop into the subdirectories, an error message say that:open /Gotest: The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: `"/"Folders` wouldn't work: `"/" + Folders`

In your case, this should work better:

```
temp,err:=os.Open("/Perkins/" + Folders)
```

(even though '`Folders`' is not a good name, '`subfolder`' would be more appropriate)

---

A more efficient way, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24783429/list-and-access-directory-in-go/24784143#comment38462810_24783429) by [chendesheng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3828156/chendesheng) (see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24784264/6309)), would be (as [in this class](https://github.com/jbowles/learning_go/blob/9c8082298a54dc70427fa0937afb14cc50d01d74/files/path_walk_directory.go)) to use [`path/filepath/#Walk`](http://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Walk):

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "os"
  "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
  filepath.Walk("/Perkins", func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
    fmt.Println(path)
    return nil
  })
}
```

---

That will list *all* the file, but you can associate it with a function which will filter those: see [this example](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Walk_a_directory/Recursively#Go):

```
matched, err := filepath.Match("*.mp3", fi.Name())
```

You can then ignore the files you don't want and proceed only for the ones matching your pattern.

Comment: I just turned the comment to an answer.

Comment: @chendesheng ok, I have added a link to your answer.

Comment: is there a way to restrict the file which we would like to list?like for example only .txt and bin file?

Comment: @user3841581 I have edited the answer and added a link to an example with a file filter.

Comment: i have got it know. and it works perfect. now im trying to search for or a particular words in the file and and convert it in Uppercase. Im using Readline but it says that my variables is undefined : this is the statement i used fi,err:=ioutil.Readfile(".")

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [filepath.Walk](http://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Walk)

> Walk walks the file tree rooted at root, calling walkFn for each file
>   or directory in the tree, including root. All errors that arise
>   visiting files and directories are filtered by walkFn. The files are
>   walked in lexical order, which makes the output deterministic but
>   means that for very large directories Walk can be inefficient. Walk
>   does not follow symbolic links.

Comment: im trying to use a simple structure. this is what i have

Comment: d, err := os.Open("/Perkins")
   fmt.Println(d.Readdirnames(-1))
    y, err:=d.Readdirnames(-1) // this is the root
    fmt.Println(y)
    for i:=0; i<len(y); i++{
     if y[i]!=" "{
      Folders:=y[i]
      temp,err:=os.Open("/Perkins"+Folders)
      z,err:=temp.Readdirnames(-1)
      fmt.Println(y[i], " have the following subdirectories:")
      fmt.Println(z)for i:=0;i<len(Element2);i++{
       if strings.Contains(Element2[i],"."){
         test,err:=ioutil.Readfile("/Perkins"+Folders+"/"+z[(len(z)-1)]+"/"+Element2[i])
         fmt.Println(" check the content of ", string(test))

Comment: i dont really get how to handle the output of the filepath.Walk because it list all the directories of the folder. is there a way to restrict the file which we would like to list?like for example only .txt and bin file?

Comment: @user3841581 if you want skip files do filepath.Match and return nil, if you want skip directories return filepath.SkipDir

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need this?
http://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadDir
And then check is type from http://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileInfo and do recursive func if it folder